# permissions dialog not redirecting in firefox v15

Tags: firefox, facebook-authentication, http-redirect

we have a problem with the facebook permissions dialog only in firefox.
The Problem is, that the redirection is not taking place.
All other Browsers work fine except the firefox.

The page which is not redirecting shows a blue fb logo with the subtitle "go to facebook.com".

the url this link is pointing to is https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=287081321311509&display=page&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.astrogeography.com%2Ffb%2Ffb_callback&response_type=code&perms=email%2Cuser_likes&fbconnect=1

but the automatic redirect to this page is not happening.
firebug is showing no specific errors only some js deprecated warnings which are not harmfull to the redirection.

as i looked in the sourcecode of the page there is a super strange a href onclick which is redirecting to itself ?! (see screenshot)

does someone know what might be the problem? all the other browsers show the same site but redirect the the dialog.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can’t reproduce your problem with FF 15.0.1/Win7; but that page with the blue logo and “go to facebook.com” usually get’s displayed, if the Auth dialog is being called inside an (i)frame …

Comment: yes sure, the site is in an iframe, it's the normal facebook container ...

Comment: you can reproduce it if you go to http://apps.facebook.com/astrogeography and test if the permissions dialog is showing or if its halting at this strange intermediate site.

Comment: Well, you’re calling `/fb/new`, and that redirects to the Auth dialog. But since there is no target attribute on that link, you stay inside the iframe – but the Auth dialog is not callable inside any kind of frame, for security reasons. And that’s why you get that page with the “go to facebook.com” link. (In other browsers this page breaks out of the frame itself, but apparently in FF it does not manage to do so.) So, put a `target="_top"` attribute onto that link, so that the Auth dialog gets called in the top window instance, and it should work as expected.